# Different behavior of REQUIRE_BASE_URL with template tags and shell command

Tags: django, requirejs

i'm using django-require module https://github.com/etianen/django-require and have some problems

I've set `REQUIRE_BASE_URL` to 'scripts' and by the `./manage.py require_init` command i've got an error

`OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/static/js'`

After changing it to `os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'scripts')` the command successful ended. But in the template tag `{% require_module 'main' %}` it prints as

`<script src="/vagrant/static/scripts/require.js'`

After changing `REQUIRE_BASE_URL` back to 'scripts' tag's script become normal

Why this happens? Any ideas? I do not want to change `REQUIRE_BASE_URL` everytime I deploy the project

My settings here:

```
BASE_DIR = '/vagrant'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'require.storage.OptimizedCachedStaticFilesStorage'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_URL,
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
)

REQUIRE_BASE_URL = 'scripts'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys 
if 'require_init' in sys.argv:
    REQUIRE_BASE_URL = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'scripts')
else:
    REQUIRE_BASE_URL = 'scripts'
```

Bad solution but it works =\